# How do I ensure my Java code built with Gradle gets updated in my Docker container?

Tags: java, docker

I am running an Angular app on top of a Java Spring based API in a Docker container.

When making code changes, I do the following;

1. Build my angular app with `ng build` if the changes are to the front end
2. Copy my built Angular app's `/dist` folder contents into my Spring codebase's `src/main/resources/static` folder (also, only if the changes are to the front end)
3. Build my Spring app with `./gradlew build`
4. Build my local docker container with `docker build --no-cache -t <user>:<app-name>`
5. Run my local Docker container with `docker run <user>:<app-name>`

When ready to run the app on a staging server, I then from my dev machine, I do a

6. Push the latest image with `docker push <user>:<app-name>`

And on the staging server,

7. Pull the latest image with `docker pull <user>:<app-name>`
8. And then run it with `docker run <user>:<app-name>`

Recently, I have noticed when making changes and running locally (Steps 1-5), the image does not have the latest code, but code from when the image was last pushed.

How do I ensure that the code gets copied correctly.

My DOCKERFILE is

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
COPY ./build/libs/<app-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/<app-name>.jar
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/<app-name>.jar"]
```

I know for sure that the `./build/libs/<app-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file is definitely being built and updated correctly, and by looking at the files inside my container I can see that the file `/app/<app-name>.jar` is not the latest.

It seems to me that the `COPY` step in the Dockerfile is not happening.

**Update**: I am aware that some kind of CI/CD pipeline will benefit me hugely. I fully intend to use one. I want to make sure that each step, manually step-by-step, works before I automate this.

Comment: Have you looked into either Github actions or Gitlab Runners? Some kind of CI/CD will help you solve this issue.

Comment: this sounds like you're using <latest> tag on staging environment and probably don't really pull the newest image because an image with that latest is already present on that machine. best way would be to go with @GabeRAMturn's sugestion and pick up some kind of cicd solution. if that's not an option right now, before running docker pull, run docker image rm <user>:<app-name>

Comment: another option would be to declare an env var in your dockerfile corresponding to the commit-sha of your application and check that with the container running on your staging env